# Not able to deregister eureka when node js app shutdown

Tags: node.js, netflix-eureka

I am using eureka-js-client to resister node js app with eureka discovery server. It working fine. but when node js service shutdown, it not deregister for discovery and still show as instance available after shutdown of service.

here how i am deregistering :

```
process.on('exit', function() {
  eurekaClient.stop() ;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used an exitHandelr for node js app and inside that deregister from eureka discovery service.

```
process.stdin.resume();

function exitHandler(options, exitCode) {
    if (options.cleanup) console.log('clean');
    if (exitCode || exitCode === 0) console.log(exitCode);
    if (options.exit) {
        eurekaClient.stop(function (error) {
            process.exit();
        });
    }
}

//do something when app is closing
process.on('exit', exitHandler.bind(null, {cleanup: true}));

//catches ctrl+c event
process.on('SIGINT', exitHandler.bind(null, {exit: true}));

// catches "kill pid" (for example: nodemon restart)
process.on('SIGUSR1', exitHandler.bind(null, {exit: true}));
process.on('SIGUSR2', exitHandler.bind(null, {exit: true}));

//catches uncaught exceptions
process.on('uncaughtException', exitHandler.bind(null, {exit: true}));
```